# How to trigger onTextChanged if i fill EditText from SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a method inside TextWatcher's onTextChanged:

```
 binding.etCitySearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(
            text: CharSequence?,
            start: Int,
            count: Int,
            after: Int
        ) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
            if (text?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                val searchCity = Runnable {
                    viewModel.getWeatherByCityName(requireContext(), text.toString())
                }
                handler.postDelayed(searchCity, DELAY)
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {
        }
    })
```

It's working ok but when i'm running my app I fill my EditText from SharedPreferences:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentCitySearchBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.etCitySearch.apply {
            setText(viewModel.getUserInput)
            setSelection(length())
        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

And of course my "OnTextChanged" method didn't triggering so my viewModel.getWeatherByCityName(requireContext(), text.toString()) is not working. How can i make TextWatcher trigger to this input?

Comment: I guess the problem here is that you need to add `TextChangedListener` before setting the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code inside onViewCreated method.

```
     binding.etCitySearch.apply {
        setText(viewModel.getUserInput)
        setSelection(length())
    }
```

Comment: I tried but i'm getting the same result

Comment: can you please share the code how you are setting the text watcher.?

Comment: Yeah i added it in question just now

Comment: In which method this code is written.?

Comment: It's in OnViewCreated

Comment: ok have you tried the suggested code at the end of or after the setting of textwatcher in onViewCreated method.?
binding.etCitySearch.apply {
        setText(viewModel.getUserInput)
        setSelection(length())
    }

Comment: Yeah it's working if i put this code after textWatcher!

Comment: great! please accept the answer if you find helpful.